# scope.$watch withing a directive returns attribute value of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attempting to setup a directive

```
project.directive('recordView', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            recordId: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: '/scripts/templates/record-view-template.html',
        controller: 'RecordViewController',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('recordId', function (value) {
                console.log(value);
                if (value) {
                    scope.resp.RecordId = 0
                    scope.resp.RecordId = eval('(' + value + ')');
                    alert(scope.resp.RecordId);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I use the directive like this

```
<record-view recordId="{{currentRecordId}}"></record-view>
```

Throwing {{currentRecordId}} in my view is proving the correct value is being set, and the directive scope.$watch is correctly triggering when the record id attribute changes, but the console.log is proving the value to be undefined.

I am not sure what I am missing here. I don't know if this matters, but this directive is being used within a separate directive.

Comment: Upvotes for a well-asked question and returning to leave an answer; just commenting that rather than using console.log, if you spend the time to really learn the browser's debugger, it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out angular does not like me calling my directive like this

```
<record-view recordId="{{currentRecordId}}"></record-view>
```

Instead it want me to call it like this

```
<record-view record-id="{{currentRecordId}}"></record-view>
```

I thought that normalization would allow me to use it like I did, but apparently that isn't the case